# Excel - How to delete specific parts of url in new column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel column that has a list of URLs, I'm attempting to update the existing URLs with a new schema. There are over thousands of ones to update so I am attempting on creating a function that can handle this for me.

Here is an example of some of my entries.

`/online-sales/new-jersey/online/top-selling-items-in-new-jersey.html`

`/retail-sales/new-york/online/top-selling-retail-shops-in-new-york.html`

They all follow the same url schema. I would like for my end result to remove the first half of the url and the `in-state.html` at the end.

I've attempted using this function `=REPLACE(A1,1,79,"")` which could give me the result I'm expecting but each cell may have a different position so I'm stuck on how to use create this function and make it dynamic if possible.

This is my expected outcome:

`/online/top-selling-items/`

`/online/top-selling-retail-shops/`

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Can you post the function you have created and tell us why it is not working? We can then assist you.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've updated my post, hope that brings more clarification.

Comment: @ovryu,,, [edit] your post and share some at least 10 sample URL,,, along with expected results,, help us to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML` functions, you can try:

```
="/" &LEFT(TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=2]|//s[last()]")),FIND("-in-",TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=2]|//s[last()]")))-1) & "/"
```

If you don't have those functions, you can use the following:

- Define a Named formula: `Formula-->Define Name`

---

```
name: seq
Refers to: =ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,255))
```

Then use this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("/", INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*999),999)),2),"/",LEFT(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*999),999)),SUM(N(LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*999),999)))>0),1)),FIND("-in-",INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*999),999)),SUM(N(LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),IF(seq=1,1,(seq-1)*999),999)))>0),1)))-1),"/")
```

Both formulas

- Split the string into "nodes" delimited by the `/`
- Return the 2nd and last node concatenated with `/`

  - Note that *the first node will be blank since your strings start with the delimiter.*
  - Using `LEFT` and `FIND`, return only the portion of the last node that is before the `-in-`
- Prepend and append a `/` to the string.

*NOTE: if, in the last node, there might be more than one `-in-`, the formula will need modification*

Both return the same result:

[image]

Comment: Your formulas are quite long, a bit of explanation could help understanding.

Comment: @MátéJuhász A search of this forum for the concept mentioned in my answer of splitting a string on a delimiter, will return lots of relevant references..